# OSX/Swift: Call a function when internet connection is established/restored

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

What I want to do is call some code when the internet connection is established or restored.

I know there are solutions out there that let me test whether an internet connection is active or not, but I am wondering if there is a way for a function to be triggered by the internet connection becoming active.

If not, what is the best workaround? Checking for a connection every x seconds? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SCNetworkReachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/index.html) APIs can be configured to generate notifications when the reachability status of an IP address or hostname changes. Create a SCNetworkReachabilityRef, then set a callback, and it will be called when a network change is detected.